# Error while playing youtube video in vlc

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, vlc

VLC cant play certain youtube videos. Currently using VLC 2.2.4 (Windowsx86). Got this error.

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'https://r14---sn-h557sn7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?lmt=1471880577481320&expire=1482936160&dur=280.427&ipbits=0&source=youtube&upn=58F0u2i73fk&itag=22&ei=AHtjWOrzM8-WoAOd9o-4DA&pl=24&ms=au&mv=m&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482914235&ip=113.193.159.186&id=o-AL9tx8jmG_NTqQbv41Elnu6WvKiF6KO6-BQ6e9Ti_luh&mn=sn-h557sn7r&mm=31&key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&nh=IgpwcjAyLm1hYTAzKgwxMjEuMjQwLjEuNDU&initcwndbps=246250&requiressl=yes&ratebypass=yes&signature=7C168CF624B8FD3E2D1F80948154BEA9A30E4C412.C96A6C26B874AC2472A068E0022E4BE33BD8AA29'. Check the log for details.

[Debug logs](https://gist.github.com/binoydev/d5f8e2128c51aedd510e0e84dea06307)

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened something due to https certificates. Mine was windows machine and restarting solved the problem.  But if someone expert in vlc check the logs and provide the root cause would be very helpful.